# Device age vs. downtime relationship

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

**The Problem:**

Retailer Y uses (for client operation purposes) a network of about 3000 devices. The whole network has 10 different models (from distinct manufacturers), aged from 0 years old 
(purchased in the current year) to 12 years old.

Each device may suffer from malfunctions for which immediate repair is requested. The total time of unavailability for each device is accounted at the end of month and we call it downtime.

The same device may have no malfunction during that month period or may have one or more unavailability periods during that month period.

Common sense says that older equipment should have higher downtimes.

**The Question:**

(a)  How can I check whether the Age variable has effective impact over the 
Downtime variable? Which statistical model should I use?

(b)  How can I account for the fact that each type of equipment should behave
differently to aging regarding downtime?

Thanks,
Eduardo

Comment: Common sense might not be correct, Eduardo.  Often, equipment exhibits a U-shaped hazard function: its downtime *decreases* during its early life, settles to a low level, and then eventually starts increasing.  This can have important implications for proposed solutions, such as regression (which, if applied naively, simply would not be appropriate in such cases).  It is often called the "bathtub curve."  About it, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathtub_curve) writes, "Many consumer products strongly reflect the bathtub curve, such as computer processors."

Comment: @ whuber. Indeed, I've started to plot first linear regressions (per model basis) and the expected efect of age over downtime was not revealed. What about if I (a) group my data into 2 categories, the first for the devices half age and newer and the second one for the devices half age and older and then (b) do some test to check if both samples come from same population. Don't know if it sounds ok. Could you suggest some statistical test that can help me to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

(a) [Linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) will capture this interaction if it exists. Basically, the idea is to plot the data where the x-axis corresponds to 'model age' and the y-axis corresponds to 'downtime', linear regression tries to fit a line to this data. Looking at the slope of this line can give you an idea of how the two variables interact. Looking at the residual errors (how well the line fits the data) gives you an idea of how meaningful this interaction is.

(b) I think [multilevel regression](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/unpublished/multi.pdf) can address this issue. The basic idea is to split the data by model type and estimate separate regression parameters for each group.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Indeed, today that's what I've done. I feel now more confortable once you've suggested it. As I said to whuber, results were not what I've expected. I mean, i saw no strong evidence of downtime decrease with age increase. I will tomorow try to shape data differently.